# How to show videos in my template using excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

Iam new to wordpress technology.I want to show my video post in template using excerpt.but by default excerpt() doesn't allow  tags.so how can i show using excerpt().Can you please tell me the answer?

Answer (score 0):

> Usually Wordpress does not all the videos to display using the excerpt function for that you have to override the code that is built in already.

Code:

```
function new_excerpt($text)
{
global $post;
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches );
if(is_array( $matches ) && array_key_exists(2, $matches ))
{
//I'm currently using only youtube and flv videos. If you use
//other videos then add those shortcodes in the following array
  $arr=array('youtube','flv');
  foreach($matches[2] as $v)
  {
     if(in_array($v, $matches[2]))
     {
        $vdo=apply_filters('the_content', $matches[0][0]);
        $text=get_the_excerpt();
        $text.="<div style='margin:20px 0 0 -115px;'>".$vdo."</div>";
     }
  }
}
return $text;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'new_excerpt');
```

**For Reference visit:** http://heera.it/show-vipers-video-excerpt#.V78XOzUnjZU

Make sure if you don't have a div around the Video file you can just do the following thing.

> **Replace Line:18 of the code**

```
$text.="<div style='margin:20px 0 0 -115px;'>".$vdo."</div>";
```

> **With**

```
$text.=$vdo;
```

That will do the trick. Share thought about this is you face any hindrance.

Comment: What file are you referring to? If it's a wordpress core file, NEVER change those

Comment: It is not the WordPress core file you have to add the code to the theme's function.php file and that will do magics over there..:)

Comment: :S Is there code in that link you've given? If so, post the code in your answer, not the link.